# Elasticsearch query and filter give different doc count when using a lucene fuzzy operator

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Using ElasticSearch v1.7.2 and a fairly large index, I'm getting a different doc count for the following two searches, which use a fuzzy search in a query_string.

Query:

```
{
  "query": {
     "query_string": {
        "query": "rapt~4"
     }
  }
}
```

Filter:

```
{
 "filter": {
    "query": {
       "query_string": {
          "query": "rapt~4"
       }
    }
 }
}
```

The filter gives about 5% **more** results than the query. Why would the document counts be different? Are there options that I can specify to make them consistent?

Note that this inconsistency only occurs when I use a moderately sized dataset. I have tried inserting just a few (<10) documents that match the filter but not the query into a clean cluster, after which both my query and my filter successfully *do* match all documents. However, in a cluster of a single index, a single type, and a couple hundred documents, I start to see the discrepancy.

Using the explain=true option, it appears that the *query* score is computed using the [Practical Scoring Function](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/practical-scoring-function.html). The explanation gives information about the boost, queryNorm, idf, and term weights. In contrast, the *filter* explanation only reports the boost and queryNorm components of the Practical Scoring Function, not the idf or term weights.

Examples of responses with explanations are below. Note that I've removed many fields from my example hit and simplified the content, so term frequencies in the explanation will not match the actual content, other than the matched word (in this case "fact"). These responses are for the *same* event. My issue is that additional hits are included in the filter response that aren't included in the query response. Their explanations look identical.

Query:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/index-name/example-type/_search" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d'{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"rapt~"}},"explain":true}'
```

And query response:

```
{
"_source": {
  "type": "example",
  "content": "to the fact that"
},
"_explanation": {
  "value": 0.10740301,
  "description": "sum of:",
  "details": [
    {
      "value": 0.10740301,
      "description": "weight(_all:fact^0.5 in 465) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
      "details": [
        {
          "value": 0.10740301,
          "description": "score(doc=465,freq=2.0), product of:",
          "details": [
            {
              "value": 0.11091774,
              "description": "queryWeight, product of:",
              "details": [
                {
                  "value": 0.5,
                  "description": "boost"
                },
                {
                  "value": 7.303468,
                  "description": "idf(docFreq=68, maxDocs=37706)"
                },
                {
                  "value": 0.03037399,
                  "description": "queryNorm"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "value": 0.96831226,
              "description": "fieldWeight in 465, product of:",
              "details": [
                {
                  "value": 1.4142135,
                  "description": "tf(freq=2.0), with freq of:",
                  "details": [
                    {
                      "value": 2,
                      "description": "termFreq=2.0"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "value": 7.303468,
                  "description": "idf(docFreq=68, maxDocs=37706)"
                },
                {
                  "value": 0.09375,
                  "description": "fieldNorm(doc=465)"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
}
```

Filter:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/index-name/example-type/_search" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d'{"query":{"filtered":{"filter":{"fquery":{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"rapt~"}}}}}},"explain":true}'
```

And filter response:

```
{
"_source": {
  "type": "example",
  "content": "to the fact that"
},
"_explanation": {
  "value": 1,
  "description": "ConstantScore(cache(+_type:example-type +org.elasticsearch.index.search.nested.NonNestedDocsFilter@737a6633)), product of:",
  "details": [
    {
      "value": 1,
      "description": "boost"
    },
    {
      "value": 1,
      "description": "queryNorm"
    }
  ]
}
}
```

When I wrap the filter in a constant score query, I get exactly the same set of results as the filter (again, more than the query), but the explanation looks a little cleaner:

Constant-score query wrapped filter:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/index-name/example-type/_search" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d'{"query":{"constant_score":{"filter":{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"rapt~"}}}}},"explain":true}'
```

And constant-score query wrapped filter response:

```
{
"_source": {
  "type": "example",
  "content": "to the fact that"
},
"_explanation": {
  "value": 1,
  "description": "ConstantScore(QueryWrapperFilter(_all:rapt~2)), product of:",
  "details": [
    {
      "value": 1,
      "description": "boost"
    },
    {
      "value": 1,
      "description": "queryNorm"
    }
  ]
}
}
```

Because the filter returns *more* results than the query, my guess is that the Practical Scoring Function ends up scoring documents that match the query with a score of 0. However, for a document that "matches" the query, none of the components of the scoring function should be zero.

Edit: I have recreated this issue on a smallish cluster of 238 documents (Note that the content of the documents is generated from an ngram language model trained on Wikipedia text.). I have posted both the [cluster](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3dd3b1t8vbmwkbf/exampleCluster.tgz?dl=0) and the [json events](https://www.dropbox.com/s/38fpt7p8k3stbkn/events.json.gz?dl=0) on dropbox. In order to see the issue on this data, run the following query, which returns the event with id=138:

```
{
 "explain": true,
 "query": {
    "bool": {
       "must_not": [
          {
             "query_string": {
                "query": "rap~",
                "fields": [
                   "body"
                ]
             }
          }
       ],
       "must": [
          {
             "constant_score": {
                "filter": {
                   "query": {
                      "query_string": {
                         "query": "rap~",
                         "fields": [
                            "body"
                         ]
                      }
                   }
                }
             }
          }
       ]
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Why did you make it a filter in the `contant_score`?  Have you tried just using the query there instead?

Comment: Good point. Using a constant_score query without a filter gives the same results as the simple query. The filter bit is what makes the difference. The following gives equivalent results to the constant_score query above:

    {
     "filter": {
        "query": {
           "query_string": {
              "query": "rapt~"
           }
        }
     }
    }

I've updated my question. Thanks!

Comment: you are querying the _all field, which is analyzed. When using the query, your query is passed through the analyzer. When using the filter, it is maybe not or in a slightly different way. Try adding explain:true or using one of the other debug features in elasticsearch.

Comment: Can you also add the request that you are using, including the `cURL` command? Feel free to obfuscate the index/type names.

Comment: It's weird because you have the `org.elasticsearch.index.search.nested.NonNestedDocsFilter`, which implies something weird is happening in your filtered version. My filtered expression is `"description": "ConstantScore(cache(QueryWrapperFilter(_all:titl~2))), product of:"` without the other stuff, implying that your filter is being modified somehow before it gets into ES.

Comment: Yeah, good point. Though I see the same results when I wrap the filter in a constant_score query.

Comment: Can you provide any of the data for this? Maybe a small snapshot of an example index?

Comment: Apologies for the delay. I just posted a dataset!

Answer (score 0):

In versions of Elasticsearch *before* Elasticsearch 5.x, `filter` at the top level indicated a [`post_filter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-post-filter.html). Post filters are generally only relevant when using aggregations.

Starting with Elasticsearch 5.0 (and later), you must explicitly say `post_filter` to avoid this confusion.

As such, the difference is that your top query is literally limiting the results to a set of matching documents. The post filter effectively matches everything, then removes results from the *hits* only without impacting the count.

> ...it appears that the query score is computed using...

Queries always compute scores and they are intended to help to properly sort items based on their relevance (score). Filters never compute scores; filters are intended for purely boolean logic that does not impact "relevance" beyond inclusion/exclusion.

To be fair, you can convert any query into a filter in multiple ways in Elasticsearch 1.x (in 2.x, all queries are also filters in the right context!), but I tend to use `fquery`. If you do this, then you should get the same results:

As a query:

```
{
  "query": {
     "query_string": {
        "query": "rapt~"
     }
  }
}
```

As a filter:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "fquery": {
          "query": {
            "query_string": {
              "query": "rapt~"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In ES 2.x, the filter simplifies too (and the query is unchanged):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "rapt~"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't quite do it. The filter *does* impact the count. Using this filter:

    {
    "query": {
      "filtered": {
        "filter": {
          "fquery": {
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "rapt~"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    }

I get exactly the same results as my filter:
    {
     "filter": {
        "query": {
           "query_string": {
              "query": "rapt~"
           }
        }
     }
    }

Again, this is about 5% more (my dataset is much larger) than the query.

Comment: And that's the _entire_ request being sent? Or is there something else? Is this touching any aliases or just normal indices?

Comment: Yes, that's the entire request. The index that I'm hitting does have an alias, but the discrepancy continues to occur when I target an individual index directly.

Comment: Can you add an example of the two separate responses to your question?

Comment: Just added, with hopefully enough detail to be useful!